# No descarga archivo Excel en Laravel8

Tags: laravel, excel

Estoy tratando de implementar la librería Laravel-Excel, de Maatwebsite, seguí los pasos de instalación, pero al tratar de descargar, va a una página en blanco, no descarga nada.

**Controller**

```
public function generarExcel() 
    {
        // intenté de ambas formas y ninguna me funciona
        //return Excel::download(new UsersExport, 'usuarios.xlsx');
        return (new UsersExport)->download('usuarios.xlsx', \Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::XLSX);
    }
```

**Export**

```
class UsersExport implements FromCollection
{
    use Exportable;
    

    /**
    * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
    */
    public function collection()
    {
        // lo simplifiqué por si era ese el problema
        return User::select('nombre')->get();
    }
}
```

**Ruta**

```
 Route::get('/usuarios/excel',[UsuariosController::class,'generarExcel'])->name('usuarios.excel');
```

Url

```
<a target="_blank" href=" {{ route('usuarios.excel') }}">Exportar archivo Excel</a>
```

Estoy utilizando Laravel 8, Laravel-Excel 3.1, PHP 8, creo tener todo bien configurado (las referencias en app.php) pero no me descarga ningún archivo.

Les agradezco desde ya.

Comment: deja el Excel:download pero quitale el trait exportabel a la clase, tambien quita el atributo blank de la etiqueta <a>

Answer (score 0):

Realicé la siguiente prueba;

```
public function generarExcel() 
    {
        return 'Prueba';
        // intenté de ambas formas y ninguna me funciona
        //return Excel::download(new UsersExport, 'usuarios.xlsx');
        return (new UsersExport)->download('usuarios.xlsx', \Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::XLSX);
    }
```

y caí en la cuenta de que nunca llegaba al Controller, de todas formas tampoco lanzaba ningún error, lo que hice fue correr el siguiente comando, para limpiar la chuche de las rutas;

```
php artisan route:chache
```

Y eso solucionó todo, me parece rarísimo igual.